# Why am I getting a 403 error when making a POST request using tetpyclient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, api, cisco

Trying to make a POST request in Cisco's Tetration API using their tetpyclient. I get a 200 response when using a get request, but 403 when making POST request with json filters for querying flows. Is my syntax for the json data incorrect or is there a syntax error in my python?

```
from tetpyclient import RestClient
import urllib3
import json
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from flask import *
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

API_ENDPOINT = "https://"
restclient = RestClient(API_ENDPOINT, credentials_file = 'path/to/credentials.json', verify = False)
get = restclient.get("/flowsearch/metrics")
print (get.status_code) ##to test if api can be reached

req_payload = {"t0": "2020-08-01T09:00:00-0700",
               "t1": "2020-08-01T10:00:00-0700",
               "scopeName": "Default",
               "limit": 10,
               "filter": {                  
                  "type": "and",
                  "filters": [
                     {"type": "eq", "field": "src_address","value": "00.000.0.000" },
                     {"type": "eq", "field": "dst_address","value": "000.000.00.00" }
                   ]
}
}

resp = restclient.post('/flowsearch', json_body=json.dumps(req_payload))

print(resp.content)
print (resp.status_code)

if resp.status_code == 200:
   parsed_resp = json.loads(resp.content)
   print (json.dumps(parsed_resp, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

I appreciate any and allfeedback!
Here is link to tetration api docs: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/workload_security/tetration-analytics/sw/config/b_Tetration_OpenAPI/m_flow-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTTP 403 is a HTTP status code meaning access to the requested resource is forbidden for some reason

It looks like the credentials you are using are not allowed to call `/flowsearch`

Comment: That was my initial thought, but wouldn't I also get a 400 or 403 for the GET request? I'm pretty new to HTTP clients so I could be wrong and may need to escalate the issue above me if its a permissions problem.

Comment: ` also get a 400 or 403 for the GET request` - not necessarily

Comment: Do get and post require different credentials?

Comment: @DaniMajor no. the same credentials should serve you.

Comment: Ok great, is there any explanation for why the get produces 200 and get post produces 403?

Comment: If there is an explanation it should be found in the docs. Another option is that your credentials are OK but the server instead of returning 400 return 403. Who created the credentials for you?